# How to modify registry settings in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, settings

I decided to make a simple proxy server using Qt/c++. So, the first thing i need to care is to enable **127.0.0.1:8080** to be my proxy server address but i don`t know how to do that in Qt although in delphi it is easy doing it in Windows OS, like this:

```
var  _reg:TRegIniFile; 
begin  
_reg := TRegIniFile.Create('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings');  
_reg.WriteString('','ProxyServer', '127.0.0.1:8080'); 
_reg.WriteBool('', 'ProxyEnable', true);  
_reg.Free; 
end;
```

so, can you please help me how to do this in Qt?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please change your title to `How to modify registry settings in Qt`. Your question has nothing to do with the internal proxy settings of Qt.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [QSettings](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html) to modify the registry entries.

```
QSettings settings("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", Setting::NativeFormat);
settings.setValue("ProxyServer", "127.0.0.1:8080");
settings.setValue("ProxyEnable", 1);
```